# wrapper div doesn't completely sorruound it's chields

Tags: css, html

Here i have a form .It has a couple of label and input elements.I have a wrapper div which is supposed to wrap it's child elements completely( in my case label and input element ).But it only wraps the label element.I need it to cover the input element too.How it can be solved?

```
<style>
  #mydiv{
     width:350px;
     height:550px;

     background:#d3a625;
     position:fixed;
     top:70px;
     left:300px;
     position:relative;

  }

  #mydiv input{

       position:absolute;
       right:0px;
       margin-left:15px;
  }
  #image{
     width:60px;
     height:60px;
     border:1px solid black;
  }
    .whole{
     border:1px solid black;
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     background:skyblue;
  }
  .design{
     color:white;
     font-size:25px;
     position:relative;
     left:30px;

  }
  .field{
     width:70%;
     height:60px;
     font-style:bold;


  }
  .wrapper{
    position:relative;
    right:40px;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' id='mydiv' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   </br>
   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='username'>username</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
             <input type='text' class='field' name='username' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>
   </br>
   </br>
   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='password'>password</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='password' class='field' name='password' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>
   </br>
   </br>
   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='password_again'>password_again</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='password' class='field' name='password_again' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>
   </br>
   </br>
   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='name'>Full Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='text' class='field' name='name' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>
   </br>
   </br>
   <div id='button'>
       <input type='submit' value='register' >
   </div>
   <input type='hidden' name='token' value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">


</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Change `position: absolute;` to `relative` for the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't wrap the input field because you set the height of the div (class='whole') to 50px. You can remove the height property or set it to auto.